# Custom function in template Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo Grid to do maintain CRUD in table. I have foreign key in my table with which I want to show the actual value in grid instead of key value. So i created custom function "getProductName". With this table instead of ProductId which is my table I am picking Product Name from Parent Table.

```
 $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            { field: "FieldId", title: "FieldId" },
            {
                field: "Product", title: "Product Name", editor: productdropdowneditor, template: **getProductName**,
                width: "auto", filterable: { ui: productFilter }
            },
            { field: "FieldName", title: "FieldName" }
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "175px", locked: true }
        ],
```

Now I problem is this function is called for each row, every time Create, Edit and Delete happen This is making my page really slow. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can create object field in your DTO, and select "productName" and "productId" in it on server.

On client:

```
{ field: "Product.productName", title: "Product Name", editor: productdropdowneditor }
```